Why are my changed files not appearing on github?
I'm maintaining the Reko decompiler on https://github.com/uxmal/reko . Recently, I used git mv to move some files from one directory in that repository (src/Analysis to src/Core/Analysis). The commit where that was done is https://github.com/uxmal/reko/commit/1378cd12017f9cfa757658652c53c7e4d88ce890. The project works fine on my Windows development machine after that. I made a few more commits, then pushed my work to github.
Now the CI pipelines for some platforms start failing. The Windows CI builds are working fine, but the Linux- and MacOS-targeting ones are not working. They are acting as if the files that were git mv'd from src/Analysis did not arrive in src/Core/Analysis, but were actually only deleted. When I go to github.com to view the HEAD of the master branch in the repository, I see the following:

amounting to only six files. There should be at least a dozen files here, and I do see them on my Windows development machine.
I've tried:

a clean git clone on my Windows machine => files exist in the repo
a clean git clone in the WSL of the same machine => files exist in the repo
looked for accidental additions to .gitignore files => nothing
made a commit https://github.com/uxmal/reko/commit/a277ed77da83e0b2fb266cf4d9a70b8c3a4c00ab where I touched all of the files which are missing. My hope was to force the files into being in the src/Core/Analysis folder. If you click that link you do see the names of the "missing" files being modified -- but when viewing the git repo the files don't appear at all!

What could be causing these files to not show up, and why is it only manifesting on Linux / MacOS environments?

Files have been moved to a "core" directory.  Try renaming it "Core".

This was indeed the case. Thanks for your insight! I've managed to find a case-sensitive file system and repaired the damage wrought by my git mv commands
